# Apache FileUtils stopped working in XPages application

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

For years I have been using [Apache Commons IO FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) in XPages. In one of my applications, the FileUtils (v2.5) suddenly stopped working a few days ago. There has neither been a Domino update, nor have there been any changes applied to the application's build path. Whenever I try to call a function from FileUtils in server-side JavaScript, exceptions like this are thrown:

> Java method 'writeStringToFile(java.io.File, string, string, boolean)' on java class 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils' not found
>
> Java method 'moveFile(java.io.File, java.io.File)' on java class 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils' not found

...even though the respective methods exist and the code used to work fine.

I have restarted the Domino server multiple times, tried to clean and build the project multiple times, removed and re-added the commons-io binary multiple times from/to the build path, but nothing fixed the problem.

Does anybody have an idea how this could be fixed?

---

Update: The stacktrace of the exceptions looks like this:

```
Java method 'writeStringToFile(java.io.File, string, string, boolean)' on java class 'org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils' not found
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:377)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:90)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTReturn.interpret(ASTReturn.java:49)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:79)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionPrototype$FunctionMethod.call(FunctionPrototype.java:169)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionPrototype$FunctionMethod.call(FunctionPrototype.java:169)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTAssign.interpret(ASTAssign.java:91)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTIf.interpret(ASTIf.java:85)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTBlock.interpret(ASTBlock.java:100)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTTry.interpret(ASTTry.java:109)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
    at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171)
    at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:197)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
    at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:686)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
    at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
    at com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:222)
    at com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
    at com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.invokePhaseMethodBinding(UIViewRootEx.java:1735)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.invokePhaseMethodBinding(FacesControllerImpl.java:450)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.access$0(FacesControllerImpl.java:444)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl$ViewPhaseListener.beforePhase(FacesControllerImpl.java:533)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
    at com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:270)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:260)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:157)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)
    at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)
    at com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)
    at com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)
```

Comment: You could try creating a bean and inside the bean call the method. If it fails it will give you a clearer error message. “Not found” could be “threw an unexpected error” like “file system full” or whatever. You are better off limit calls into Java into a bean that does the actual work

Comment: @stwissel: I added the stacktrace of the exception to the question.

Comment: Half of it is the JS runtime. Put it in a bean

Comment: @stwissel: Taking a look at the stacktrace from the exception thrown inside the bean revealed that the org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils was not loaded from the commons-io binary, but from another binary in the WEB-INF/lib directory. I don't know how this is even possible since that binary was not even within the build path, but after completely deleting it from the project, FileUtils works like before. Thanks very much for your help and pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: Most welcome. Build path is subject to OSGi, so loading a different version depends on what modules have been loaded. Glad it worked out